# How can I solve this paradoxical importing?

Tags: typescript

I have two classes *Lamp* and *Switch*. Since I have separated the two classes in different files, now I'm having a paradoxical importing:

- *Lamp* imports *Switch* to call Switch.on(this)
- *Switch* imports *Lamps* to resolve its interface.

**lamp.ts**

```
import Switch from './switch.ts';

export default class Lamp {
    state: 'on' | 'off' = 'off';

    constructor () {
        Switch.on(this);
    }
}
```

**switch.ts**

```
import Lamp from './lamp.ts';

export default class Switch {
    static on (lamp: Lamp) {
        lamp.state = 'on';
    }

    static off (lamp: Lamp) {
        lamp.state = 'off';
    }
}
```

Comment: create an interface called Switchable that Lamp cam implement. Then both will import that one.

Comment: Your current (pun absolutely intended) code doesn't make much sense from a modelling perspective. A lamp instance needs the class of all possible switches to make it on when it's created? A switchable interface would be one improvement, switches shouldn't have to know about lamps specifically, but it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve with this.

Comment: also, do read on OOP principles, practices and patterns, they will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface, let's call it `Switchable`. That `Lamp` can implement.

That way `Switch` relies on an abstraction instead of the concrete `Lamp` class.

It would look something like this:

```js
interface Switchable {
  state: 'on' | 'off';
}

class Lamp implements Switchable {
  state: 'on' | 'off' = 'off';

  constructor() {
    Switch.on(this);
  }
}

class Switch {
  static on(switchable: Switchable) {
    switchable.state = 'on';
  }

  static off(switchable: Switchable) {
    switchable.state = 'off';
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Switchable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'on'%20%7C%20'off'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Lamp%20implements%20Switchable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20'on'%20%7C%20'off'%20%3D%20'off'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Switch.on(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Switch%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20on(switchable%3A%20Switchable)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switchable.state%20%3D%20'on'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20off(switchable%3A%20Switchable)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switchable.state%20%3D%20'off'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)'s a link to the playground with the code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to repeat the type of state in Lamp

Comment: I agree, but for some reason tsc complains the property in lamp doesn't match the interface if I do `state = 'off'` only.

Comment: String types are a bit weird. An enum might be better.

Comment: indeed a State enum does make remove the need to specify the type again but it's not really related to the OP's question. I'll put the code in the answer if he asks for it. :)